# can't retrieve dropdownlist.selectedvalue on Page Load?

Tags: drop-down-menu, count, pageload

i have a drop down box , it has value that is retrieve from datasqlsource, however i want to get the count value on page load but it seem that it did not count

```
'Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
    'Dim ds As New DataSet


    'Dim connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("myProject").ConnectionString
    'Dim myConn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)

    'Dim cmd = "SELECT * FROM Group Where groupID='" & DropDownList1.SelectedValue & "' AND customerID='" & Session("customerID") & "'"






    'Try
    '    myConn5.Open()
    '    Dim myCmd5 As New SqlCommand(cmd5, myConn5)
    '    adapter.SelectCommand = myCmd5
    '    adapter.Fill(ds, "Group")
    '    ' txtQuan.Text = adapter.SelectCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString()
    '    adapter.Dispose()
    '    myCmd5.Dispose()
    '    ' txtQuan.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count
    '    If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count >= 10 Then
    '        lblNoPpl.Text = "The  group is full"
    '    Else
    '        Dim numLefts As Integer = 10 - ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count
    '        lblNoPpl.Text = numLefts.ToString() + "space left"



    'Catch ex As Exception
    '    MsgBox("Can not open connection ! ")
    'End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use cmd.ExcuteScalar() method retrieve a count,the sql should be

SELECT **COUNT(*)** FROM Group Where groupID='" & DropDownList1.SelectedValue & "' AND customerID='" & Session("customerID") & "'"